# How to add icon button beside dropdownlist globally using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on a MVC4 web application.Everything working fine but in the end of the project i got one new requirement in which i have to show a Plus icon beside of each dropdownlist present on almost 20 pages like.

[image]

In the above picture in item dropdownlist i had added icon manually.But i want to add this icon with every dropdownlist present in full project. On clicking this icon one pop-up will open with a text box. User will enter new item in this and save.

**Common structure of page is :**

```
<div runat="server" id="divFormLayout" class="formLayout">
<div class="TabSectionL" style="width: 99%">
        <span class="TabSectionHeader">Item Details</span>
        <table cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Item
                </td>
                <td>
                    @if (ViewData["ItemDesc"] != null)
                    {
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.str_itemdsc, (SelectList)(ViewData["ItemDesc"]), "-Select-", new { @class = "validate[required] cairs_item_dropdown", tabindex = "1" })

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        @Html.DropDownList("str_itemdsc", new SelectList(""), "", new { tabindex = "1" })
                    }

                </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Problem :** How i can add plus icon dynamically beside each dropdownlist.

Comment: some googling gave me this .. chk if works for u..
 
http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/12/jquery-bind-images-to-dropdownlist-in.html

Answer (score 1):

Like so:

```
$("select").each(function(){
    $("<a class='icon or whatever'></a>").insertAfter($(this));
});
```

Comment: No need for a loop here, you can pass a selector to `insertAfter` and it will add the content to each element matched

Answer (score 0):

You can use some jquery codes to achieve that.

As your dropdowns are inside a `<td>` tag, you can select your DDLs and then, append the icon to its parent - actually the `<td>`. So, put this code in your `_Layout`:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select").parent().append("<img src='...' />");
    });
</script>
```